# Overlay video with other video in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a short and a long mp4 video. In the long video, I would like to replace the visual with a part of the visual of the short video. Additionally, I would like to keep the audio of the long video throughout.

The following set of commands work. However the concat and audio replacing seems to add a slight delay to the video, which makes the audio slightly out of sync from the video.

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i short.mp4 -t 2.0 -vcodec copy -an v1_short.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i long.mp4 -t 6.0 -vcodec copy -an v1_before.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 8.0 -i v_before.mp4 -vcodec copy -an v1_after.mp4.mp4
ffmpeg -i v1_before.mp4 -i v1_short.mp4 -i v1_after.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [1:v] [2:v] concat=n=3:v=1 [v]" -map "[v]" out_temp.mp4
ffmpeg -i long.mp4 -i out_temp.mp4 -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a out_final.mp4
```

How can I do this without the audio getting out of sync?

I am using ffmpeg version 4.0.2.

Comment: Your commands as a whole don't make sense. The output files generated in first three commands don't match with input files used in concat cmd. Also mapping in last cmd should fail given the earlier commands. Verify all commands you have pasted here. How much is the desync? 2 seconds?

Comment: i corrected the filenames. the offset is less than 2 seconds. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: what version of ffmpeg? Anyway typically ffmpeg command line questions should be asked in superuser of AV.stackexchange, FWIW...

Comment: ffmpeg version 4.0.2